# Cannot run php from /usr/share after upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, php5, postgresql

I had phppgadmin and phpmyadmin running on Ubuntu 12.04
After upgrading to 12.10 (using do-release-upgrade), when I try to go to localhost/phppgadmin I get the source code of index.php instead of the code executing.

I wrote a small php script and put it in /var/www and it runs fine. so I know that php is working and that the problem is with the directory.

What decides what directories php can run from? There are no directories explictly mentioned in php5.conf.

Comment: # a2enmod php5 paste here the result (?!)

Comment: it just says "Module php5 already enabled"

Comment: Just checked that moving the script that works fine in /var/www fails when I move it into /usr/share/phppgadmin - I get the source instead of the result (it just calls phpinfo())